# How to find cutoff frequency with more than one resistor

Tags: resistors, cutoff-frequency, high-pass-filter

[image]

I have the above circuit and I want to find the cutoff frequency. Z_eff,in is my load. I have created a transfer function:

[image]

How is it possible to find the cutoff frequency? Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: That transfer function is invalid without specifying Vin (from the source)

Comment: Ouh yea. I guess that Vin just needes to be multiplies with the rest of the equation. Or am i mistaken?

Comment: Fix the question is my advice.

Comment: To me, Vin is clear - however, what is Vout? It seems that the common point of the 4 resistors is meant.

Comment: Vout is the point connected to Z_eff,in, as it is my load resistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the cut-off frequency even without the transfer function. Simply find the time constant T realized by C and the total resistance Rtot connected to C. Then, the frequency is wo=1/T.